# Can i use Cursor loader instead the asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm studying and learning about Android Java world.

I'm building my first Android App, using Json to get all data from the application, and Java to display it. I created an activity with a Chat between two users, and I am using Asynctask to get and insert the Data.

But today I had an issue, because I have to update the listview everytime that a user inserts a new message, and Asynctask doesn't do that. I searched more about that, and some user said to me that I should use Cursor Loader instead the asynctask.

My questions are, whats the difference between both?

Do Cursor Loader reload my Listview automatically everytime that new Data is inserted into my Database?

Am i able to get the Json Data using Cursor Loader?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, telling you how a CursorLoader works in a simple answer would be confuse because it envolves a lot of code if you preetend to use Content Providers, but there is plenty of Google material explaining how it works!

As stated in [Android Developers - CursorLoader Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) page:

> A CursorLoader runs an asynchronous query in the background against a ContentProvider, and returns the results to the Activity or FragmentActivity from which it was called. This allows the Activity or FragmentActivity to continue to interact with the user while the query is ongoing.

Also, in the [second part](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/handle-results.html) of that tutorial there is a section that answers  your second question:

> To display Cursor data returned by CursorLoader, use a View class that implements AdapterView and provide the view with an adapter that implements CursorAdapter. The system then automatically moves data from the Cursor to the view.

And for the third question: you can do anything with Java! :)

There is also a good tutorial on this available at Voggela: [Android SQLite database and content provider](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).